# How to handle special characters in url as parameter values?

Tags: java, javascript, html, http, spring-mvc

Can anyone suggest how to handle below url as values of parameter of strLocation is haveing special charecters ? Thanks in advance

```
http://localhost:8080/safp/contacts/FirmAddress.do?btnAction=FirmAddress&firmId=122379069&strLocation=!@#$%^&*()_+&async=true&newAccID=112
```

Comment: Use `encodeURIComponent()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: @SJuan76...JAVA(spring_mvc)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to encode your URL string with special characters.When encoding a String, the following rules apply:

> - The alphanumeric characters "a" through "z", "A" through "Z" and "0"    through "9" remain the same.
> - The special characters ".", "-", "*", and "_" remain the same.
> - The space character " " is converted into a plus sign "+".
> - All other characters are unsafe and are first converted into one or    more bytes using some encoding scheme. Then each byte is represented
>     by the 3-character string "%xy", where xy is the two-digit
>     hexadecimal representation of the byte. The recommended encoding
>     scheme to use is UTF-8. However, for compatibility reasons, if an
>     encoding is not specified, then the default encoding of the platform
>     is used.

For example using UTF-8 as the encoding scheme the string `The string ü@foo-bar` would get converted to `The+string+%C3%BC%40foo-bar` because in UTF-8 the character ü is encoded as two bytes C3 (hex) and BC (hex), and the character @ is encoded as one byte 40 (hex).

Answer (score 9):

Use [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html).encode()

```
String url="http://localhost:8080/safp/contacts/FirmAddress.do?btnAction=FirmAddress&firmId="+URLEncoder.encode("122379069","UTF-8")+"&strLocation="+URLEncoder.encode("!@#$%^&*()_+","UTF-8")+"&async=true&newAccID=112";
```

Note: Don't `encode` the whole url because it will also encode the `//` from `http://`