# How to use / in parameter during rest webservice call from angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, rest, url

I need to send a value like `app/role` as parameter through rest webservice url from angularjs

In controller.js

```
var roleName = 'app/role';
checkRole.check({'roleName': roleName}, function(data){}
```

In model.js

```
popModel.factory('checkRole', function ($resource) {    
    return  $resource('./rest/checkRole/:roleName',{roleName:'@roleName'},{
        check: {'method':'GET'},
    });
});
```

The rest webservice call in java

```
    @GET
    @Path("/checkRole/{roleName}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response checkRole(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @PathParam("roleName") String roleName);
```

When i pass it i am getting browser console error as

```
Bad request response from the server.
```

For normal parameter values like `'Test', 'Solution', 'Application' etc`. If i use with `/` as a parameter no process is done and i am getting error.

Comment: Tested with your exact code and works fine for me. Angular just encodes the slash. And using Jersey, Jersey decodes it when it comes in.

Answer (score 0):

`/` is reserved character for `GET` request. So, you can't use them directly. If you use them, you would get `Bad Request` Error.

One of the solution can be to encode the URL on client side and decode it on server.

Reference:
[Characters allowed in GET parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455578/characters-allowed-in-get-parameter)
[How to handle special characters in url as parameter values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515616/how-to-handle-special-characters-in-url-as-parameter-values)