# Angular Routing symbol '=' was ignored in the matched URL

Tags: angular

I have set the Routes as below in app-routing.module.ts

```
{ path: 'token/:token', component: AppComponent }
```

The destination URL is

```
localhost:4200/token/23s893rhjkdsdfhjk234=
```

But when I enter this url into browser and get the final url is

```
localhost:4200/token/23s893rhjkdsdfhjk234
```

**the '=' is missing,**
could I know why the '=' is ignored and how to keep it in url?
Thanks

Comment: This could help you, https://stackoverflow.com/a/19515748/6635464

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my answer based on ngShravil.py's link is that encode the token part of the URL which is **23s893rhjkdsdfhjk234=** here by using **encodeURIComponent**, and decode it when route received it by using **decodeURIComponent**.

Comment: Correct answer from JinWu.